# Timestamps are not updating while attaching data in pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm creating a row in pivot table using the following attach statement.

```
$music = Music::find(1);
$music->users()->attach(1);
```

This inserting a row in pivot table, but it is not updating the timestamp. The timestamp remains as `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Is there any way to update the timestamps in pivot table?

Answer (score 267, accepted):

> If you want your pivot table to have automatically maintained
>   created_at and updated_at timestamps, use the `withTimestamps()`
>   method on the relationship definition.

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Role')->withTimestamps();
```

- For Laravel 4.2: [Working With Pivot Tables](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables)
- Laravel 5.0: [Working With Pivot Tables](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables)
- Laravel 5.1: [Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)
- Laravel 5.2: [Filtering Relationships Via Intermediate Table Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)
- Laravel 5.3: [Filtering Relationships Via Intermediate Table Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)
- Laravel 5.4: [Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)
- Laravel 5.5: [Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)
- Laravel 5.6: [Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)
- Laravel 5.7: [Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)
- Laravel 5.8: [Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Does this have to be on both sides of the relation? Or just one side?

Comment: @Noitidart I just checked and it seems it needs to be on both sides of the relationship to work.