# Laravel null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint for pivot table

Tags: postgresql, laravel

I am getting following error while saving the data in the pivot table

```
Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (4, 10, 16, null, null). (SQL: insert into "child_packages" ("child_id", "package_id") values (10, 16))
```

here is my code for saving data in the table

```
    $child = $this->child_section->create($input);


    $packages_ids = Input::get('package_id');
    $child->Packages()->sync($packages_ids);
```

and in the child model

```
 public function Packages()
{
    return  $this->belongsToMany('FoodPackage');
}
```

For database I am using postgresql

Comment: Can you post your model?

Comment: Try adding public $timestamps = true; in your model

Comment: The one that you are describing as the child model.

Comment: I have remove the `created_at` column form the schema and it works. Thank you for your time John Roca..

Comment: You dont have to remove your created_at column. Anyway if that solves your problem.

Comment: You have to add ->withTimestamps() in the relationship:
public function Packages()
{
    return  $this->belongsToMany('FoodPackage')->withTimestamps();
}

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726602/timestamps-are-not-updating-while-attaching-data-in-pivot-table

Answer (score 2):

You have add method whitTimestamps();

Example:

$this->belongsToMany(Model::class)->withTimestamps();

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through