# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::withTimestamps()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create a relationship in laravel with timestamps. I have this app that allows customers to request a job to a marketplace. When a freelancer on the marketplace finds a job their interested in they propose to complete the job and a new row is queried into the freelancer table.

Here is the code creating the relation:

```
$marketplace->freelancers()->create([
   'request_id' => $id,
   'user_id' => $user->id
]);
```

Here is the Marketplace Model relationship code:

```
    /**
     * A request may have multiple freelancers
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function freelancers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\MainFreelancers')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Here is the Freelancer Model relationship code:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function mainMarketplace()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\MainMarketplace');
}
```

When trying to run the very first code block I keep getting this Laravel Error: 
`BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::withTimestamps()`

In the short term, I just manually added a `strtotime()` but I'd prefer to utilize what Laravel offers. Does anyone have suggestions?

Note I have reference a previous stackoverflow question here: 
[Timestamps are not updating while attaching data in pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726602/timestamps-are-not-updating-while-attaching-data-in-pivot-table)
But unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: you don't need to attach the timestamp() method if you are using `one to many` relationship.

Answer (score 6):

`withTimestamps();` is used in Many to Many relationships where you want to declare that there are created_at and updated_at columns in the join table.

> $withTimestamps   Indicates if timestamps are available on the pivot table.

As the exception rightly points out, `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany` does not have a `withTimestamps()` method.

https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.html

Comment: Aww, that's unfortunate. So I should I just continue to use `strtotime()` to manually define the created_at & updated_at columns?

Comment: @SolomonAntoine Can you post your migration files and your Model files.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want your pivot table to have automatically maintained
>   created_at and updated_at timestamps, use the withTimestamps method on
>   the relationship definition:
>
> `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withTimestamps();`

[Eloquent relationships.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

In the case of a **belongs to many** relationship, `withTimestamps()` manages your timestamps for you automatically. But you are implementing a **has many** relationship, so you have direct access to the timestamps.

Int this case, you can use an accessor in your model to format the date:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute()
    {
        return date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A", strtotime($this->attributes['created_at']));
    }
```